# Oracle Function Performance Significantly Worse Than Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a formula I need to re-use to get a certain date. The example below is made up for demonstration purposes.

```
select max(order_date)
from orders
where processing_date < sysdate
;
```

I want to have the result of this accessible across a range of processes/scripts and so thought it would be best to encapsulate it inside a function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_GET_DATE RETURN DATE AS 
    D_DATE DATE;
BEGIN

    select max(order_date)
    INTO D_DATE
    from orders
    where processing_date < sysdate
    ; 
    
  RETURN D_DATE;
  
END F_GET_RF;
```

However, when I try using it in a Where clause, the performance is significantly lower than if I'd have just used a subquery. The problem is, I don't want to use a subquery in lots of different places in case the logic changes, plus DRY and all that...

This seems to run indefinitely:

```
select *
from order
where order_date = F_GET_DATE;
```

However, this runs as normal

```
select *
from order
where order_date = (select max(order_date)
                    from orders
                    where processing_date < sysdate);
```

I can also query the function in the Select without any issues:

```
select f_get_date
from dual;
```

Is there anything I can do to make the function 'work'. I can't figure out why the performance would be taking such a giant hit.

Comment: Functions often impede the optimizer, make them much, much slower.

Comment: Maybe: `select *
from order
where order_date = (SELECT F_GET_DATE FROM dual)`;

Comment: This seems to work @LukaszSzozda. Any ideas why?

Comment: @TomBennett: Perhaps, `(SELECT F_GET_DATE FROM dual)` will execute once because of `FROM DUAL`? @Lukasz: Is that right?

Comment: You might be surprised once you compare the execution plans for those two statements.

Comment: Function caching I believe

Comment: @shahkalpesh yes, but because of "Scalar Subquery Caching"

Comment: @TomBennett your original version is slow because it is executed once for each row. Placing it in a subquery means it is executed only once, similar to your example that uses a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very big topic with a lot of nuances. In short, you need to read about "PL/SQL Context switches", consistency of PL/SQL functions in SQL, optimization techniques like `PRAGMA UDF`, `RESULT_CACHE`, or `deterministic` clause, etc.

For example you can read my series: http://orasql.org/2013/03/13/deterministic-function-vs-scalar-subquery-caching-part-3/

Comment: PRAGMA UDF looks promising but unfortunately I'm still on 11g. (select F_GET_DATE from dual) seems to do the trick though

Comment: @TomBennett `(select F_GET_DATE from dual)` - it's called a Scalar Subquery Caching (SSC). You can read more about it by the link above

Comment: @TomBennett you can just add `deterministic` clause into your function definition, it will do the trick too

Comment: I've done some research on using 'deterministic' and it should not be used where it is possible that the function output could one day return something different for the same function input. As this is calling a database table, I don't think it's worth the risk and will instead simply use (select F_GET_DATE from dual).

Comment: Read the link above: deterministic function results are cache only during one `fetch` call.